# How to Pass this parameter?

Tags: c#, notepad

I have trying to mirror the output screen to .txt file.By my below code i can able to mirror the output screen to text file. When executing the `obj.OutputFile("First text");` there is no problem But some times i need print like `obj.OutputFile("Second text {0}",text);`

I got the exception during the second line execution

> No overload for method 'OutputFile' takes 2 arguments test document

How do i clear my exception?

I want to my code which is to be accept different number of arguments passing.

**My Code**

```
class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = "Sample";
            Program obj = new Program();
            obj.OutputFile("First text");             
            obj.OutputFile("Second text {0}",text);    
            Console.ReadKey();    
        }
        public void OutputFile(string text)
        {

            string path = "Example.txt";

            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path))
                {
                    tw.WriteLine(text);
                    Console.WriteLine(text);
                }
            }    
            else if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path,true))
                {
                    tw.WriteLine(text);
                    Console.WriteLine(text);
                }
            }
        }         
    }
```

I am totally new to this c#. So i hope your answer would be simple.

Comment: obj.OutputFile(string.Format("Second text {0}",text));

Comment: Your OutputFile method expects 1 parameter. You've given it 2 (separated by commas) and the compiler is confused.

Comment: Totally unrelated to your issue, you could avoid the if /else if block by noting that when `File.Exists` is true, you give `true` as 2nd argument of `Streamwriter` ctor otherwise (when `File.Exists` is false) you give nothing (so you're indirectly calling the `Streamwriter` ctor for which that 2nd argument is `false`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your call for OutputFile doesn't seem correct. You have `obj.OutputFile("Second text {0}",text);` while the method signature is `public void OutputFile(string text)`, which means it requires one parameter.

All you have to do is to change your call to:

```
obj.OutputFile(string.Format("Second text {0}", text));
```

And if you are using C# 6 you can make it even better:

```
obj.OutputFile($"Second text {text}");
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
obj.OutputFile("Second text {0}",text);
```

to

```
obj.OutputFile(string.Format("Second text {0}",text));
```

EDIT:

Your function definition for OutputFile has one parameter. With the comma between the strings you have two parameters instead of the expected one parameter.

Comment: You could add a quick description at the end explaining why their line of code was wrong.